# rewrite an Immediately-Invoked Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a script from AWeber, for a popup form, and I want to customize it a little bit..

It currently opens the popup when the page loads. I want it to run as a click event for a button.

The problem is: it uses an immediately-invoked function. And since I'm a newbie and not familiar with this kind of pattern yet, I can't figure it out. I've read about it, but I'm still not completely understanding it.

So, I've tried to rewrite the script to a simple pattern, but it doesn't work!

So, would you please help figuring out what the problem is with my new function?

And/or simplify/explain the other function for me?

**The first Function:**

```
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//forms.aweber.com/form/id.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-formid")
```

**My attempt (jQuery) :**

```
function createAweberScript() {
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.type='text/javascript';
    script.id='aweber-wjs-formid';
    script.src='//forms.aweber.com/form/id.js';
    jQuery('body').append(script);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery( 'a.button' ).click(createAweberScript);
});
```

Comment: why exactly doesn't it work? *"it doesn't work"* isn't good enough..

Comment: Does the original version work if you put it in exactly the same place?

Comment: @KevinB , I don't know why it doesn't work?! :D ... I mean by "it doesn't work": when I click the button, which is `a.button` on my code, the popup form doesn't appear! is that clear enough? sorry, just let me know how can I make it clear...

Comment: does the script tag get added? does the script load successfully? do any errors occur? follow the process that happens when you click and figure out where it stops.

Comment: @Quentin , Yes it does work when I put it in exactly the same place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wrap the immediately-invoked function in a regular function, and call that function in the `click` handler:

```
function createAweberScript() {
    // start Aweber script
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//forms.aweber.com/form/id.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-formid"));
    // end Aweber script
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('a.button').click(createAweberScript);
});
```

You could pick this apart and write your own function, yes, but this is easier to understand and maintain: if the Aweber function ever changes, you just have to replace everything inside your `createAweberScript()` function to update it.

Note: I got a 404 for `http://forms.aweber.com/form/id.js`; I'm assuming that's not really the URL you are trying to use. If so, you might want to check it.

Comment: yeah, that's right, I've just changed the URL to be more portable/wiki-style example

Comment: @SomeOne Great; glad it helped!